Could not autowire. No beans of 'PubSubTemplate' type found
enter image description here
Here i have used the pubsub inbound channel adapter for sending and receiving the message from publisher and subscriber. This code is taken from the google cloud pubsub documentation only, here all the required dependency are installed and rest other thing is perfectly fine.
Here, below i am providing the code of the inboundConfiguration class

import com.google.cloud.spring.pubsub.core.PubSubTemplate;
import com.google.cloud.spring.pubsub.integration.AckMode;
import com.google.cloud.spring.pubsub.integration.inbound.PubSubInboundChannelAdapter;
import com.google.cloud.spring.pubsub.support.BasicAcknowledgeablePubsubMessage;
import com.google.cloud.spring.pubsub.support.GcpPubSubHeaders;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.example.mediumpubsub.config.pubsubConfiguration;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.ServiceActivator;
import org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel;

import org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandler;


@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class inboundConfiguration {
    private final pubsubConfiguration pubsubConfiguration;

    @Bean
    public PubSubInboundChannelAdapter messageChannelAdapter(
            @Qualifier("pubsubInputChannel") MessageChannel inputChannel,PubSubTemplate pubSubTemplate) {
        PubSubInboundChannelAdapter adapter =
                new PubSubInboundChannelAdapter(pubSubTemplate, pubsubConfiguration.getSubscription());
        adapter.setOutputChannel(inputChannel);
        adapter.setAckMode(AckMode.MANUAL);

        return adapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel pubsubInputChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "pubsubInputChannel")
    public MessageHandler messageReceiver() {
        return message -> {
            log.info("Message arrived! Payload: " + new String((byte[]) message.getPayload()));
            BasicAcknowledgeablePubsubMessage originalMessage =
                    message.getHeaders().get(GcpPubSubHeaders.ORIGINAL_MESSAGE, BasicAcknowledgeablePubsubMessage.class);
            originalMessage.ack();
        };
    }
}

this is outboundConfiguration for refrence
package org.example.mediumpubsub.outbound;

import com.google.cloud.spring.pubsub.core.PubSubTemplate;
import com.google.cloud.spring.pubsub.integration.outbound.PubSubMessageHandler;
import org.example.mediumpubsub.config.pubsubConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.MessagingGateway;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.ServiceActivator;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandler;

public class outboundConfiguration {
    private final pubsubConfiguration pubsubConfiguration;

    public outboundConfiguration(org.example.mediumpubsub.config.pubsubConfiguration pubsubConfiguration) {
        this.pubsubConfiguration = pubsubConfiguration;
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "pubsubOutputChannel")
    public MessageHandler messageSender(PubSubTemplate pubsubTemplate) {
        return new PubSubMessageHandler(pubsubTemplate, pubsubConfiguration.getTopic());
    }

    @MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel = "pubsubOutputChannel")
    public interface PubsubOutboundGateway {

        void sendToPubsub(String text);
    }
}


and also outbound controller

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/send")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class outboundController {
    private outboundConfiguration.PubsubOutboundGateway messagingGateway;
    @PostMapping("/pubsub")
    public void sendMessage(@RequestParam("message") String message) {
        log.info(message);
        messagingGateway.sendToPubsub(message);
    }
}

i strongly need the solution of this problem regarding pubSubTemplate, because i in all other youtube videos regarding this this error is not occuring

Instead of panicking from the message of your IDE (which probably doesn't do everything for auto detecting all the beans) have you just tried running it? Although I suspect it will fail with a NullPointException in your controller (hint there are no required arguments in your controller).

You need to annotate the outboundConfiguration class with @Configuration. Spring is not picking it up and is not creating your beans as a result.
